# XSL - How to ouput nested text-elements at the correct position

Tags: xslt

I am trying to create an xsl-stylesheet that outputs my xml-contents in the correct order.
Here is an example:
XML:

```
...<p>This is<mark> a nested <b>text</b></mark></p>...
```

XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<html> 
<body>
  <h2>
    <xsl:value-of select="html/head/title"/>
  </h2>
  <div style="border:1px solid black;margin:30px;padding:30px;box-sizing:border-box;">
    <xsl:for-each select="html/body/div[@class='toc']/table/tr/td/a">
      <p><a>
        <xsl:attribute name="href" namespace="uri">
          <xsl:value-of select="current()/@href"/>
        </xsl:attribute> 
        <xsl:value-of select="current()"/>
      </a></p>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </div>
  <xsl:for-each select="html/body/div[@class='chapter']">
    <div style="border:1px solid black;margin:30px;padding:30px;box-sizing:border-box;">
        <xsl:attribute name="id" namespace="uri"><xsl:value-of select ="current()/@id"/></xsl:attribute> 
        <p><xsl:value-of select ="current()/@id"/></p>
        <xsl:call-template name="rec">
          <xsl:with-param name="parents" select="current()"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
        
    </div>
  </xsl:for-each>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="rec">
<xsl:param name="parents"></xsl:param>
  <xsl:for-each select="$parents/*">
    <xsl:if test="name() = 'img'">
      <img class="{@class}" src="{@src}" style="max-width:100%;"/>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="name() != 'img'">
      <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:if test="name() != 'figure'">
          <xsl:value-of select ="current()"/>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:call-template name="rec">
          <xsl:with-param name="parents" select="current()"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This outputs:

```
This is a nested text
a nested text
text
```

What I am trying to get:

```
<p>This is<mark> a nested <b>text</b></mark></p>
```

I have tried just to include a CSS-Stylesheet (which would get rid of this particular problem), however this does not seem to work with images (e.g.), which won´t be displayed but will occure inside most documents.
The XSL-Stylesheet is supposed to be working with multiple documents (I wrote an exporter, that creates xml-files, that roughly follow the same syntax). The important part should only be the recursive function inside `<xsl:template name="rec">`.

Help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The input you show is the same as the output so it is not clear why you need to transform anything or which transformation you want. To preserve the input structure when doing transformations with XSLT, I usually recommend to use push styles processing with matching templates and apply-templates.

Comment: I need to transform the xml, because the original file does not seem to display any images.
Is there any possibility I can differenciate between the elements that need to be transformed and those who do not?
Is there a documentation for that "push styles processing" you suggested?

Comment: Well, yes, any tutorial on XSLT will certainly show you how to use e.g. `<xsl:template match="img"><img class="{@class}" src="{@src}" style="max-width:100%;"/></xsl:template>` and `<xsl:apply-templates/>` and so on instead of relying on for-each and call-template. The info section has a link to a PDF copy of a practical introduction XSLT and XPath.

Comment: https://cranesoftwrights.github.io/books/ptux/index.htm is the link from the info section on xslt to the book on XSLT and XPath by G. Ken Holman.

Answer (score 1):

Basic push style, structure and order preserving processing usually relies on the identity transformation template plus custom templates for each node you need to transform e.g.

```
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="img">
      <img class="{@class}" src="{@src}" style="max-width:100%;"/>
  </xsl:template>
```

The duplicated text in your wrong output is created by the repeated use of `xsl:value-of` in the recursive, named template. If you treat text as nodes and let any copying be handled through adequate templates, like the identity transformation template, you don't output text values several times.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am completely new to xslt though, so I might come back to you.